# Change of Variable for Finding Total Photon Number Density

Tags: integration

I am doing physics work, but I must be overlooking something very obvious with my mathematics. I have an integral that is easier to solve by change of variable. However, when I change the variable, I get a negative sign that doesn't vanish, so my final solution is negative (which doesn't make sense in this context, because my solution is strictly positive). I must be making a mistake. Here is my work: 
$$N = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{8\pi}{\lambda^{4}}\frac{1}{e^{hc/\lambda kT}-1}d\lambda$$
I set:
$$x = \frac{hc}{\lambda kT}$$
This means:
$$\lambda = \frac{hc}{xkT}$$
and
$$d\lambda = -\frac{hc}{x^{2}kT}dx$$
I make this substitution:
$$N = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{8\pi}{\left(\frac{hc}{xkT}\right)^{4}}\frac{1}{e^{x}-1}\left(-\frac{hc}{x^{2}kT}\right)dx$$
This simplifies to:
$$N = -8\pi\left(\frac{kT}{hc}\right)^{3}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2}}{e^{x}-1}dx$$

At least, I still have the negative sign. It should be positive, as the integral is the Riemann Zeta function and it evaluates numerically as a positive number (2.4 to be exact). The negative sign messes this calculation up, as my number N should be positive.

Can anyone spot where I may or may not have made an arithmetic error? Thanks.

Comment: You can get the parentheses (or any other pair of delimiters) to adjust to the size of their content by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to change the bounds of the integral when you made the substitution. Correcting that will cancel the pesky negative sign.

Comment: I knew it was something obvious. I appreciate the quick response!